# masterpage in MVC 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 5 years experience in developing ASP.NET and now decided to shift myself towards MVC framework. I would like to know how create masterpage and content page to design a basic application where I want to place two textboxes UserID and Password and Login button to authenticate ID from LDAP and display text valid login or invalid login.

Comment: Why didn't you use the "internet application" template. It's a good way to start learning about the structure of MVC, since you will have a working example in an instant.

Comment: I am kinda clueless..I think I should do more research instead of asking questions here like a newbie :) ..thanks for the top Dev..if u wud like to add anything else i would appreciate.

Comment: There are no master pages in MVC, only Layouts. http://www.asp.net is your friend.

Comment: thanks Chris and Dev.

Comment: I don't know wether you've already found a tutorial but ASP.Net generally provides one for you. [Here's the link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4)